# skip and limit function not work in rails rake file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, cursor, mongoose

Hi am learner of rails and mongodb. i am doing application on rails with mongodb as backend. 
am having huge content of data to retrieve on single request at the time am having error is "cursor error", for that i used a trick is to partition of all data to small content. on that concept am having a bug, my code is to separate

```
     competitionsAry = NFL_Competition.where(sdi_sport_id: teamSdi_Sport_id)

 puts "Total competitions:" + competitionsAry.count.to_s // it has 2330 count on this step  

      execCount = competitionsAry.count / 100

      if competitionsAry.count % 100 != 0

          execCount += 1

      end      

      execCount.times do |ctr|

        skipValue = ctr + 100

        competitions = competitionsAry.skip(skipValue).limit(100)

 puts "Now the competition length is: " + competitions.length.to_s // here also same amount of 2330 data
```

i know "competitions = competitionsAry.skip(skipValue).limit(100)" here is the problem. 
   skip and limits functions are not working. even i tried "competitions = NFL_Competition.skip(skipValue).limit(100)" no result what am exception can anyone help how to solve this and how to use skip and limit function on rails. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ya i got it i used ruby array slice concept in this by that.

```
competitions = competitionsAry[skipValue,100]
```